# Absolute values in axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following graphic, the values in the x axis represent distances, where I coloured by group, so for group A the distances are represented to the right, while for group B the distances are represented to the left (had to make them negative to plot like this). Is there a way to represent the values to the left of 0 as positive (absolute value)? To be clear, instead of -20, -40, -60, -80, I would like to show, to the left of 0: 20, 40, 60 and 80.

[image]

Comment: thank you. If u want it I can mark it as the answer if you put it in the right place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `abs()` function to the labels argument of `scale_x_continuous()`:

```
... + scale_x_continuous(labels = abs)
```