# how to remove minus sign from "negative area" of y axis (ggplot2 r)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot this ggplot freq-counts with `ggplot2` but without the negative sign in values under 0. I can't find how to do it. So if someone can help me I would appreciate it.

[image: img]

Comment: use the function `scale_y_continuous`. Set whatever labels you want using the `labels` argument. Specify where the labels go using the `breaks` argument.

Comment: @JohnJ. it's nicer to go with a transformation option. Wanting positive labels doesn't mean you should have to set your own breakpoints and labels manually.

Comment: @GregorThomas, that's true. Assuming Mel wants just the same labels, just without the `-` sign, your solution is certainly best. Still, I think it's good to mention the manual option, on the off-chance anyone isn't already aware of it. Sometimes ggplot's presets aren't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Absolute values in axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462326/absolute-values-in-axis-labels)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass functions to the `labels` argument of `scale_y_continuous` that will be used to transform the axis tick labels. For all positive values, we can use the absolute value function `abs`.

Here's a demonstration:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:3, y = -1:1), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs) ## add this line to your plot code
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much,it worked!